# Enabling real-time mode for Linux SPI driver

Tags: linux, spi

I have an application that uses an ARM device running Debian Stretch (soon to be Bullseye) that is using SPI for high speed point-to-point communications to another device.  I am using the spidev driver.  I am seeing a lot of latency in each transaction, taking up to 700 microseconds for a burst of 256 bytes at 10MHZ.  I have to transfer this burst every 1 millisecond.

I want to test reducing the latency in the Linux SPI driver.  I see that struct spi_device has some fields to control that:

```
From spi.h
@rt: Make the pump thread real time priority.
@cs_setup: delay to be introduced by the controller after CS is asserted
@cs_hold: delay to be introduced by the controller before CS is deasserted
```

How do I set these?

I've done a lot of searching about this but I can't find the connection between setting `struct spi_device` and any external mechanism.

Comment: First of all, you are **not** supposed to use `spidev`. It's wrong. Write the proper in-kernel driver. Second, Linux is **not** an RTOS, you have to tune it to be _close enough_.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that the kernel was compiled with real time extension.  For the most part, it is responsive enough.  Why is spidev "wrong"?  And has no one addressed the latency issue?

Comment: Because it's not supposed to be used. `spidev` is only for prototyping the real driver. Yeah, some legacy firmwares use it, but it's all by a mistake.

Comment: OK. Lets pretend I'm using some other driver than spidev, even though most everyone in Google searches is using it, and get back to the real question.  How do I set these fields in struct spi_device and send them to the driver?

Comment: On one hand it's a controller's property and only PL022 currently supports it. Otherwise you have to patch the kernel to add that support to another SPI host controller and enable via Device Tree or ACPI.

Comment: On the other, you mentioned `struct spi_device`, so there are only few devices support that: CAN driver for MCP251xFD and ChromeOS EC. Look at their implementation on how to enable that: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/can/spi/mcp251xfd/mcp251xfd-core.c#L2124 and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/platform/chrome/cros_ec_spi.c#L749.

Comment: Thank you @0andriy for this information.  I was hoping for an easier answer but it is what it is.